# Amadeus: How to get a successful response from the GET /shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel endpoint?

Tags: api, amadeus

Seems like no matter what hotel or check-in check-out dates I try, the `GET /shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel` endpoint always returns no availability. The `GET /shopping/hotel-offers` for a city always returns one or more hotels that have availability. I understand that these can be cached results but then using any of those hotels in the `GET /shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel` endpoint returns no availability

Example 1

```
GET https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=NYC

(RESPONSE TRUNCATED FOR READABILITY)

{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "hotel-offers",
      "hotel": {
        "type": "hotel",
        "hotelId": "BWNYC133",
        "chainCode": "BW",
        "dupeId": "700101379",
        "name": "BEST WESTERN BOWERY HANBEE HTL"
        ...
      "available": true,
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": "15F1E33CA0571B94E27F2BA26CA4319C8A097B500D737AB68088E93AC813D2BC",
          "rateCode": "SRS",
          "rateFamilyEstimated": {
            "code": "SRS",
            "type": "C"
          },
          "boardType": "BREAKFAST",
          "room": {
            "type": "A1Q",
            "typeEstimated": {
              "category": "ACCESSIBLE_ROOM",
              "beds": 1,
              "bedType": "QUEEN"
            },
          }
     ...
    ],
  ...
}

Immediately followed by
GET https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=BWNYC133

RESPONSE
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 400,
      "code": 3664,
      "title": "NO ROOMS AVAILABLE AT REQUESTED PROPERTY"
    }
  ]
}
```

The same is true no matter what hotel in any city I try. Am I doing something wrong? I've been playing with the endpoints for a few hours now and have only been able to get a successful response from the hotels by city endpoint.

Appreciate any help provided.

**EDIT**

My issues are continuing in production now. I am getting no availability from `/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel` or `/shopping/hotel-offers/{offerId}` endpoints.

```
GET https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=NYC&hotelIds=XTNYC130,ONNYCMIM,DSNYC132&checkInDate=2020-05-01&checkOutDate=2020-05-03&roomQuantity=1&adults=2&radius=5&radiusUnit=KM&paymentPolicy=NONE&includeClosed=false&bestRateOnly=true&view=FULL&sort=NONE

(RESPONSE TRUNCATED FOR READABILITY)

{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "hotel-offers",
            "hotel": {
                "type": "hotel",
                "hotelId": "XTNYC130",
                "chainCode": "XT",
                "dupeId": "700070576"
                "name": "DUANE STREET HOTEL",
            },
            "available": true,
            "offers": [
                {
                    "id": "394DF124A254A86DD6DA5D1A3084B543DFA462740EDAE34023151D479266C4DE",
                    "rateCode": "GMT"
                }
            ],
            "self": "https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=XTNYC130&adults=2&checkInDate=2020-05-01&checkOutDate=2020-05-03&paymentPolicy=NONE&roomQuantity=1&view=FULL"
        },
        {
            "type": "hotel-offers",
            "hotel": {
                "type": "hotel",
                "hotelId": "ONNYCMIM",
                "chainCode": "ON",
                "dupeId": "700128992",
                "name": "HOTEL MIMOSA"
            },
            "available": true,
            "offers": [
                {
                    "id": "547EA4B5F7F716DF083DFD19D857DAE0F1B6820E753D080F310737C5374AF857",
                    "rateCode": "BAR"
                }
            ],
            "self": "https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=ONNYCMIM&adults=2&checkInDate=2020-05-01&checkOutDate=2020-05-03&paymentPolicy=NONE&roomQuantity=1&view=FULL"
        },
        {
            "type": "hotel-offers",
            "hotel": {
                "type": "hotel",
                "hotelId": "DSNYC132",
                "chainCode": "DS",
                "dupeId": "700224946",
                "name": "The Ludlow Hotel"
            },
            "available": true,
            "offers": [
                {
                    "id": "CC8CD3A64562527B6330E1A317584E78B68537B1E682115497037D28CB466FDE",
                    "rateCode": "RAC"
                }
            ],
            "self": "https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=DSNYC132&adults=2&checkInDate=2020-05-01&checkOutDate=2020-05-03&paymentPolicy=NONE&roomQuantity=1&view=FULL"
        }
    ]
}

GET https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=XTNYC130&adults=2&checkInDate=2020-05-01&checkOutDate=2020-05-03&paymentPolicy=NONE&roomQuantity=1&view=FULL

RESPONSE

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 400,
            "code": 3664,
            "title": "NO ROOMS AVAILABLE AT REQUESTED PROPERTY"
        }
    ]
}

GET https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=ONNYCMIM&adults=2&checkInDate=2020-05-01&checkOutDate=2020-05-03&paymentPolicy=NONE&roomQuantity=1&view=FULL

RESPONSE

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 400,
            "code": 3664,
            "title": "NO ROOMS AVAILABLE AT REQUESTED PROPERTY"
        }
    ]
}

GET https://api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=DSNYC132&adults=2&checkInDate=2020-05-01&checkOutDate=2020-05-03&paymentPolicy=NONE&roomQuantity=1&view=FULL

RESPONSE

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 400,
            "code": 3664,
            "title": "NO ROOMS AVAILABLE AT REQUESTED PROPERTY"
        }
    ]
}

GET https://api.amadeus.com/v2/271FFDEF4E7FD5E1EEB10BFE59B0880B5F6AF4DCA73BA57E5489FDFE7E95AFCD

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 400,
            "code": 477,
            "title": "INVALID FORMAT"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing temporary problems with some of our hotel providers test systems which is leading to slower than usual response times or timeouts as in your example. We tried the same request, and for most of the time, it does work, so while we are working with our providers to resolve this issue, you can try to do the request a few times until you have a response.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Please see my edit. I am still having these issues even in the production environment